Boots straight to BIOS
Was on 22.04 LTS. Ran the upgrader in the OS to Mantic 23.10. Did the restart and now it goes straight into the bios.
Tried restarting several times keep going into the bios. It sees the drive in the bios, so I'm guessing the startup is borked, but no idea how to go back restoring it.
Busy day of troubleshooting. So if I'm reading things correctly Ubuntu still thinks its a 22.04. I did find some instructions on running boot repair which I was able to do from booting via the usb unbuntu installer thumb drive and via the boot repair bootable drive as well. Both indicated GRUB was reinstalled and should work fine, but after several attempts the exact same issue. the Lenovo logo appears and instead of the OS loading it takes me to the bios.
My main concern is capturing some vm's had I had running on the vm so hoping someone comes up with a better strategy I'll try to capture the necessary files and do a clean install of ubuntu latest edition.

When boot-repair starts select advanced options and select purge grub before install it

That did it. Took a couple of tries to get there, but I'm in. Thank you.
