Stuck in boot loop after upgrading to 23.10 (mantic minotaur)
I've been at it all day and really am desperate. I'll make this short:
HP machine, desktop installation. Wanted to upgrade to latest lts from non lts, i think it was 23.04, but not sure. Had to go through 23.10. After do-release-upgrade stuck in boot loop, can't start from efi/ubuntu/grubx64 nor the shimx one. No errors, just black screen and back to HP's boot menu. I can't seem to access grub by holding shift. Live usb (22.04) works. Secure boot is disabled, but I tried both.
PLEASE help, literally anything would be appreciated at this point. I really need this fixed ASAP.

@guiverc sry, I'll try to clarify a bit more

@guiverc ok i updated the question, but im not very good with technical details. I hope it's better now. What you said about the grub entry is mostly gibberish to me :/. I did try to boot with debiand/grubx64 and i got the need to load kernel first error, YES. Noooo idea what that means tho

The suggested fix is install a supported release like 22.04 which you say does work.

@David, officially the 23.10 release is still supported despite the time/clock (you can view https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release and upgrades to it are still [currently] open. No ML post has gone out triggering me (or ubuntu-news team) to post EOL on fridge etc), so at least to me, this question 'beat the clock' (ie. Ubuntu Release Team haven't yet declared EOL; they can wait for packages to finish as once EOL all building/fixes will get lost).

Was just going from the release site and comments that others were making yesterday.

@David, yeah; I'd not have been surprised if I'd posted EOL notice ~24 hours ago, or even this morning (my local time; AEST).. but it's not happened yet. No response yet to a query in #ubuntu-release (~10 hours ago) but it'll happen.  A few users are experiencing this with 6.5 kernel (23.10 & 22.04 with HWE stack) I gather

@David I don't mind installing 22.04 again, but i have no means of stoing a backup thw size of my current data and I couldn't find a way to safely re install without losing it. Lot's of work and life stuff are on there

Fresh install 24.04 instead. You can use the live USB to backup the data in your home folder to a different hard drive/different partition.

Ubuntu 22 is based on Grub 2.06, while 23 and 24 are based on Grub 2.12. when I made this upgrade, I used boot-repair, and advanced options, and selected purge grub before installing it. see the comment on this question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1519650/1698042

This is just an FYI, but I wrote an answer about re-installing at https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533   but my first comment (now deleted) asked about you install (Server? Desktop?) which you didn't answer; it's useful for desktop installs only & ubiquity or calamares installs too (24.04 uses ubuntu-desktop-installer so more limited); so is possible with 22.04... but I'd for sure BACKUP data first, as its easy to make mistake & destroy everything...

@guiverc I did edit my post to include the information you asked for after you asked for it. It's a desktop installation. Anyway, I don't have remotely enough space to backup even essentials only, so I'll have to risk it. Thanks for the link I'll check it out in a bit
